# findViewWithTag gives null object reference when used inside loop

Tags: java, android

in an android app i have 4 buttons for which i've given the tags 1,2,3 and 4 respectively, and i want to use for loop to change the text in each button if it matches (or not) a certain value in my code, "i" in the for loop goes from 1 to 4 and i of course convert it into a string..but when i run the code it gives me null object reference and the app crashes
the error occurs when the app calls ans.setText(); or any other method..
**i did try to initiate an object and find it by it's tag outside a loop and it worked with no problems

```
for(int i=1;i<=4;i++){
           Button ans=(Button) view.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i));
            if(i==correct()){
                ans.setText(x+y+"");
            }else{
                int z=rand.nextInt(100)+rand.nextInt(100);
                if(z==x+y){
                    ans.setText(z+rand.nextInt(100));
                }
                else{
                    ans.setText(z);
                }
            }
        }
```

error given :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.braintrainer.MainActivity.go(MainActivity.java:52)
```

Comment: What's `view` you're calling ´findViewWithTag()` on? Does it have those buttons as its children?

Comment: ahm uhhh..i'm total a beginner and i don't know what do you mean by " it have those buttons as its children"..and i don't know what view i'm calling actually..i just make onClick method and give it parameter (View view) i couldn't understand why this parameter is for actually even googling it didn't help much

Comment: The `Button`s are not children of the `view` that was clicked on, and hence you get nulls from find calls.

Comment: can you post your Layout XML file?

Comment: in Android every UI element has an unique id (set in layout xml). You can try to call `findViewById(R.id.your_button_id)` instead `findViewWithTag` for every button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind your layout and parse the views using the childCount instead of the tags.

Assuming it's a Linear Layout you have (but you can adjust it accordingly):

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_layout);
    for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
            //add your checks here and set the text using v.setText("...");  
        }
```

NOTE: in your loop, you define i as an integer and then you check if `i == correct()`. Does your correct() method return an integer that's supposed to be equal to i? Maybe you have more issues on the code that you're not sharing here.

Comment: i have a few more buttons and views in my layout though, would using the childCount iteration affect them as well ? 
and yeah the method correct returns an integer that is checked if it's equal to i or not..the value that is returned is always between 1 and 4 (inclusive)

Comment: It would be affected then, yes. Unless the aforementioned 4 buttons are right next to one another and could be grouped in a nested layout inside the one you have now

Comment: I guess i could put the buttons i want in a grid layout and iterate through it..thanks man :)

Comment: glad I could be of help!